# Dataframe take two column and take action depending on value

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has two column fk (foreign_key) and fk_1. In the dataset, they are called both fk.

I want to get rid of fk_1 so that there is only 1 column with fk.
fk can contain a number, a #-hashcode, so can fk_1.

Now I only want to keep the number, but if fk and fk_1 have a number. I would like to create a new entry which takes the fk_1 value, so the old one can take fk value

Example:

```
FK        FK-1     Name Expected Result
1         #abc07zy Test  1
#abc2Z90  2        Beta  2
3         4        Alpha 3 and a new entry with value 4
```

So the total list would look like:

```
FK  Name
1   Test
2   Beta
3   Alpha
4   Alpha
```

I tried to do something with `ifelse` and `grepl` on `"#"`, but that only works on one column. 
And I don't see how I can achieve that number 3 and 4 will become two entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pivot_longer()` and `str_detect()` solution

```
#required libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

#example data
example <- data.frame(FK = c(1, "#abc07zy", 3),
                      FK_1 = c("#abc2Z90", 2, 4),
                      Name = c("Test", "Beta", "Alpha"),
                      stringsAsFactors = F)
#solution
solution <- example %>%
  pivot_longer(c("FK", "FK_1"), values_to = "FK") %>%
  filter(str_detect(FK, "^\\d*$"))
```

Comment: The Reg expression shall not work. As I updated the example. I figured out that #code can contain numbers after abc part. The abc part is always there if the value is a #code

Comment: @Helper have you tried it? I adjusted  my example data to your new example and it still gives your expected output. This RegEx filters for **only digits**, so it doesn't matter if there are any digits after _#abc_ part.

Comment: Yes I tried it. It seems to do the same as my other solution (explained in one of the comments). Only with less code. Although there are duplicates. But I can filter those out.

Answer (score 1):

We can combine `FK` and `FK_1` columns using `unite`, get all the numbers from the column using `str_extract_all` and get data in separate rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  unite(FK, FK, FK_1, sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(FK = stringr::str_extract_all(FK, '\\b\\d+\\b'))  %>%
  unnest(FK)


# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  FK    Name 
# <chr> <fct>
#1 1     Test 
#2 2     Beta 
#3 3     Alpha
#4 4     Alpha
```

Comment: This doesn't do what I would like. If I have 29 objects (which I test this with) where FK and FK_1 both are a number, then it should give 48 objects back. But it only returns 29. I think the unite does this? The #code filtering works.

Comment: @Helper This works on the example you have provided. If your actual dataset is more complicated than the data you have shared please share your actual data using `dput`.

Comment: I updated the dataset. It seems that FK #code can also contain numbers, which makes the reg expression subtracting those numbers. The #code always start with prefix abc which might be followed by numbers and other characters.

Comment: @Helper yes, just needed small change in regex. I have updated the answer which works on the data shared. Can you check if it works on your original data?

Comment: No It doesn't work. I have to do propper testing to see what went wrong. But the dataset goes back from 63k to 1k. Although I think I found a solution to the problem. By first replacing all #code with abc, then use your first answer to solve the problem

Comment: @Helper We can only help you based on the data you showed. My previous answer worked for the data that you had shown earlier, my this answer works for the data that you have shown now.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about coalesce here, not sure if it's the best option though:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(FK=ifelse(grepl("^#", FK), NA, FK),
         FK_1=ifelse(grepl("^#", FK_1), NA, FK_1),
         FK=coalesce(FK, FK_1)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=c(FK, FK_1), values_drop_na=TRUE) %>%
  distinct(FK=value, Name)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  FK    Name 
  <chr> <chr>
1 1     Test 
2 2     Beta 
3 3     Alpha
4 4     Alpha
```

Comment: It seems to work on my sample dataset that has 29 objects where FK and FK_1 both number. All other attributes (name is not the only attribute) are being copied. I need to test it on real dataset

Comment: It doesn't work on 63k dataset. It turns to 98k, and even the first entry there FK is a number and FK_1 is not turns to two entries. While it should just take FK as it can leave the #hash-code out.

Comment: Please provide a more minimal working example then.